# how to test click event of relative layout in robotium

Tags: android, click, android-relativelayout, robotium

I am using **robotium** to create a test project of my project.there is a **relative layout** in my project.i have given a **click** event for this relative layout.i need to test this.but i dont know how to test click event of a relative layout.layout content is just an image.so i could not call

```
     solo.clickOnButton(string);
```

can anybody help me to do this..

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution.it is really simple.i just give

```
solo.clickOnView(myrelativelayout);
```

it is working fine